# How to escape multiple chars in Databricks or Spark

Tags: sql, csv, apache-spark, escaping, databricks

I am using Databricks and creating external sql tables on a fly from csv, using sql queries. The problem I face is my last header column when created, carries '\n' character. And this causes issues in my queries. Below is my query where I already used escape option once. When I try to use another escape option, Databricks throws error. Any idea on how to use multiple escape options?

%sql
create table if not exists myTable
using CSV
options ("header"="true", "inferschema"="true","multiLine"="true", "escape"='"' "escape" = '\n')
location ''

Thanks in advance

Comment: UPDATE: Apache Spark has accepted it as bug and said will get it fixed in release 3.0. More can be found @ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26804